# Unable to schedule training job to Azure Machine Learning AKS cluster

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am using the preview feature of configuring an AKS cluster via Arc in Azure Machine Learning Studio and attempting to submit a job for training however it gets stuck in Queued state with the following message:

*Queue Information : Job is waiting for available resources, that required for 1 instance with 1.00 vCPU(s), 4.00 GB memory and 0 GPU(s). The best-fit compute can only provide 1.90 vCPU(s), 4.46 GB memory and 0 GPU(s). Please continue to wait or change to a smaller instance type*

I am not too sure exactly what this is telling me because (aside from the grammar) the job requirements are LESS than what is available so why is it blocking? Also its telling me to change to a smaller instance type, which I did and it still gave me the same.

Anyone come across this or know how to get past it?

Comment: Can you please share the configuration that you are trying.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=azure-studio#create-a-schedule-in-studio

Comment: @Ram-msft I am not trying to attach Kubernetes for model deployment, I am trying to attach kubernetes as an 'Attached Compute' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-attach-arc-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Create and attach an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster limitations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-attach-kubernetes?tabs=python#limitations